# How to use play-jersey in playframework?

Tags: playframework, jersey

I read the play-jersey home page in [bitcucket](https://bitbucket.org/psartini/play-jersey/wiki/Home).

However, I still have no idea how to use it in my application.

Where to set "jersey.path"?
jersey.path = /api

I also tried to create a resource in "app/rest/resources" folder just like this:

```
@Path("/rest/hello")
public class HelloRessource {
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response helloJson() {
        return Response.ok("Hello").build();
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public Response helloXml() {
        return Response.ok("Hello").build();
    }
}
```

When I visit "localhost:9000/rest/hello", I got a 404 error.

Who can tell me how to set jersey in play?  btw, i use play-1.2.5.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you've set `jersey.path = /api`, then why would you try to access `http://localhost/rest/hello`? Where's the `/api`? Also, this setting goes  where all other configuration settings go, that is into `conf/application.conf`.

Comment: @Carsten , thank you for your comment! In fact, I don't know where to set jersey.path, so I leave everything as default. The resource is created in "app/rest/resources" folder.

Comment: As I told you in my comment, you put it into `conf/application.conf`.